# Convert a list of fields to structtype object which is a SparkR schema

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

We have to get the schema of dataframe in SparkR as StructType and list as list of fields, e.g:

```
str(schema)
#List of 2
# $ jobj  :Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x563114ff5900> 
# $ fields:function ()  
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "structType"

schema <- schema(output_count)
 
fields <- schema$fields()

fields
#[[1]]
#StructField(name = "word", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE)
#[[2]]
#StructField(name = "count", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE)
```

I found that SparkR API exposes a method:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/R/

but not sure how to use it as a beginner in SparkR

My attempt:

```
schema <- schema(output_count)
str(schema)
#List of 2
# $ jobj  :Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x563114ff5900> 
# $ fields:function ()  
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "structType"
```

I try to get it as a structtype

Comment: I am not sure about the objective, but you may utilize [`SparkR::dtypes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/dtypes.html) which produces something very similar.

Comment: Hello Vivek
This dtypes return the data format , same as str, example str(schema)
which is a list, but I need this schema to be return as a StructType not list, like a cast if you want or some workaround against this list to create a StructType please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then the below codes at least produces the type of output you explained in the question.

```
df <- SparkR::createDataFrame(iris)
lapply(SparkR::dtypes(df), function(x) SparkR::structField(x[1], x[2]))
```

The output is:

```
[[1]] 
StructField(name = "Sepal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE)
[[2]] 
StructField(name = "Sepal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE)
[[3]] 
StructField(name = "Petal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE)
[[4]] 
StructField(name = "Petal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE)
[[5]] 
StructField(name = "Species", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE)
```

If you further use `do.apply` with `SparkR::structType`,

```
do.call(SparkR::structType, lapply(SparkR::dtypes(dd), function(x) SparkR::structField(x[1], x[2])))
```

then the output is like below:

```
StructType
|-name = "Sepal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Sepal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Length", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Petal_Width", type = "DoubleType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "Species", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
```

Comment: I am getting while trying to cast the answer :(
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Oh for that, there will be small 'tick mark' just below the vote button - to mark it as an 'accepted answer'. You may still mark it as 'accepted' even if you are unable to vote. :). I am glad the solution worked for you.

Comment: Sure, did that and thanks !

Is it possible in SparkR to get the schema by calling a method of a Java class also please?

E.g. the path to the class: com.comp.risklab.moniker.JMonikerLensResolver
by calling resolveLensAndGetSchema
Is it exposed any API like SparkR.callJMethod or something.
I can also open a new case for the above request,
Thanks Vivek

Comment: I am not sure, may be others in the community can help 

Comment: Hi Vivek

I am trying to get in SparkR the structtype elements/structure, so far I can only get the fields like:
where 
> sparkR.callJMethod(struct_schema_megdp(output_count), "fields")
[[1]]
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField id 38 

[[2]]
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField id 39

Comment: I cannot follow your question; maybe adding some reproducible example codes will help me understand it better.

Comment: So, I have this Java(Spark) object struct_schema_megdp(output_count) coming from:

> struct_schema_megdp <- function(output_count)
+ {
+   return(sparkR.callJStatic("com.ubs.risklab.moniker.JMonikerLensResolver", "resolveLensAndGetSchema", moniker$moniker_provider(), moniker$soft_lens(moniker$lens_identifier("output_counts"))))
+ }
> struct_schema_megdp(output_count)
I have to print the elements of this Java object, which is a the StructType but a java class that contains for each output filed (fieldName, type):
I also opened a new request for this new one

Comment: This is my Spark(Java) object:

> str(struct_schema_megdp(output_count))

Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x560cacd6d3e8>

Comment: For simplicity, I assign this object to > x <- struct_schema_megdp(output_count)
and can get the fields but not the fieldName and type please
> sparkR.callJMethod(x, "fields")
[[1]]
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField id 42 

[[2]]
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField id 43

Comment: Expected output will be:

> struct_schema(output_count)
StructType
|-name = "word", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "count", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE